# Windows SDK 8.1 installation hangs on "Acquiring Windows Software Development Kit"

Tags: windows-10, installation, visual-studio-2010, sdk

I am using Visual Studio and I would like to build a project with a different SDK version of the one I have currently installed. Therefore, I downloaded the Windows SDK 8.1 (my visual studio has by default the Windows SDK 10.xx) and I am trying to install it.

However, the installer is stuck at 0% on "Acquiring Windows Software Development Kit".

I think that it might be a problem of firewall or proxy since I am trying to make it work on my work laptop. However, I would like to be sure about that. Is there a way to know what's happening behind the scenes of the GUI of the installer? Is there a way to get a log of what's failing or where the installer is hanging on?

Comment: Yes;  It most likely is a firewall issue.  The Windows 8.1 SDK installer allows you to create an offline installer.  You might want to try `sdksetup /quiet /layout C:\Temp\ADK` to accomplish exactly that.  You are aware the Windows SDK is designed to be (mainly) backwards compatible.  This is the reason you can install Windows 10 SDK on systems not running Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried it but it seems that nothing is happening.

Comment: Also: nothing is created in the folder "Temp\ADK" (which I created on purpose. I think you just wanted to write "Temp\SDK" , but it does not matter since it is just a folder name).

Comment: You can get rid of `/quiet` and it will tell you what it's doing, but it sounds like a proxy issue, which means you will have to make the appropriate changes to the proxy and/or run it on another machine NOT connected to that machine.

Comment: So, its been a little while since I have done this but the way to accomplish this is through the visual studio installer and not an individual sdk download.

Comment: Hi @SeñorCMasMasc, from these answers it seems instead that the "suggested" way to do this is through the standalone installer 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9268c2c0-d00d-406a-a31d-bfaf6606061e/how-to-install-other-windows-10-sdklow-versions-in-vs-2019?forum=vssetup

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I had same problem and I have uncheck all setup options aside from first one - SDK. Then installation continue.